# I wonder why python with homebrew doensn't work in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have installed python3 with homebrew, but it keeps making errors when i run.
i think problem is that i'm not working at homebrew file, so i've searched but couldn't get solutions.

```
which python3
```

give me

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
```

and i'm using Python 3.9.9 64-bit interpreter in /opt/homebrew/bin/python3

How can i make my VScode work with homebrew python3[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjDEb.png)?

Answer (score 1):

If you focus on the terminal you can probably press `arrow up` to see which command Visual Studio code used to run your program. It'll probably reveal the path of the `python` interpreter.

I used the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51488832/467650 to make Visual Studio Code run with the desired `python` interpreter (which also for me was the `homebrew` one:

I pressed `⇧⌘P`, found `Python: Select Interpreter` and entered the full path of the `python` executable. After that Visual Studio Code run just fine.