# How to run python commands in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using mac air m2 now and I'm trying to use python in vscode. I downloaded python from vscode, created a file called 1.py, and entered the command 1 + 1

```
[Running] python -u "/Applications/securety/programming/Python coding/1.py"
/bin/sh: python: command not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.009 seconds
```

got this error

How can I fix the error?

I also downloaded python and python extension pack from vs code

Comment: `python` from vscode is an extension for the editor... Have you installed python in your system? what do you get if you enter `python` in the terminal?

Comment: still the same error

Comment: try installing python in your system separate from vscode, also test adding #!/usr/bin/env python3 as the first line in your code

Comment: Can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51488832/18359438) solve your issue?

Comment: you could try running the same command on a virtual environment because you set global modules and install libraries by reserving a new python core program from scratch to use later, if not try to fix your python instalation path

Comment: Did you download the Python language from python.org, or the Python VScode extension that lets you use Python on VScode (but doesn't install it)?